# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\arcsin\left ( x\arccos x \right )\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

How to evaluate the following integral

> $$\mathcal{I}=\int_{0}^{1}\arcsin\left ( x\arccos x \right )\mathrm{d}x$$

Mathematica can only give me a numerical solution $\mathcal{I}\approx 0.40926\cdots$.

So I want to know if there is a closed form for the integral.

Comment: For most random integrals you write down, the answer is: NO! there is no closed form.  Why would you think this one has a closed form?

Comment: @GEdgar Why would you think it has not?

Comment: Most of random integrals do not have closed forms, by the way there is something called the Rich algorithm which will tells you if it has or not, if the answer is positive it will even give you the exact result! If the answer is no you can define your integral as a new function and then try to see if it is linked to other special functions and maybe some application :)

Comment: After a bit of messing around, I got
$$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos^2 x }{\sqrt{1-x^2\cos^2 x}}(x\sqrt{1-x^2\cos^2 x})'dx$$

Comment: One basic idea is expanding $\sin^{-1}(y)$ $\int_0^\frac\pi2 \sin^{-1}(x\cos(x))\sin(x)dx$ which does converge on $|y|=|x\cos(x)|<1$. Wolfram functions has $\int x^a \sin^b(x)\cos^c(x)dx$ in closed form [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cos/21/01/10/01/02/01/) for the resulting integral. However, the possible result will be long to write out.

Answer (score 4):

By using the [formula](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/7/2/a/72a1058ad2087aec467af24bddcf9479.png),
$$\int_a^b f(x)\space dx=(b-a)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^{2^n-1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{2^{n}}f\left(a+\frac{m(b-a)}{2^{n}}\right)$$
We have
$$\int_0^1\sin^{-1}(x\cos^{-1}x)~dx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^{2^n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+1}}{2^n}\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{m}{2^n}\cos^{-1}\dfrac{m}{2^n}\right)$$

Comment: [This test](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5E%28m%2B1%29%2F2%5En+asin%28m%2F2%5En+acos%28m%2F2%5En%29%29%2C%7Bm%2C1%2C2%5E10-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C10%7D%5D) supports your result. Maybe you need to take the real part of it?

Comment: this method is explained by this Wikipedia page in Catalan
https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A8tode_d'exhausti%C3%B3


I am not sure how this double sum can be taken further

Answer (score 3):

The most we can do is find a closed form expression in elementary functions with a given precision.

First, let's note that

$$x\arccos x < 1$$

$$0 \leqslant  x\leqslant 1$$

Taking into account this equality we use Taylor expansion of $\arcsin x$

$$\arcsin x =x + \frac{x^3}{6}+ \frac{3}{40}x^5 + ...$$

$$x^2<1$$

Considering only the first three terms here we need to compute three integrals

$$\int_{0}^{1} x\arccos x \; dx=\frac{\pi}{8}$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left ( x\arccos x \right )^3\mathrm{d}x=\frac{3\pi(2\pi^2-15)}{512}$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left ( x\arccos x \right )^5\mathrm{d}x=\frac{5\pi(54\pi^4-1470\pi^2+9485)}{16588}$$

Using the obtained results we get

$$\mathcal{I}\approx \frac{5\pi(54\pi^4-606\pi^2+58301)}{442368}$$

The approximation error here is about $0.00034$

If we want a more precise expression, we have to include the next term of the Taylor series, $\frac{5}{112}x^7$, etc.

**A physicist's approach**

I would prefer the following approach

$$\mathcal{I}=\int_{0}^{1}\arcsin\left ( x\arccos x \right )\mathrm{d}x$$

To get the approximate value of $\mathcal{I}$, i push the integral operator inside the $\arcsin$ function

$$\mathcal{I}\approx \arcsin \left ( \int_{0}^{1} x\arccos x \; dx \right )=\arcsin\left ( \frac{\pi}{8} \right )=0.4036$$

The approximation error here is about $0.006$

We see that, unlike the first, the second method stands out for its simplicity and comprehensibility, although the majority of mathematicians would consider it illegal.

Comment: How do you justify the second method?

Comment: By Jensen inequality...but one has to estimate the Jensen gap

Comment: Illegal may be, but nice !